# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report! - Dec 2017

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, monthly

## Welcome Our SharePoint Stack Exchange Valued Contributors.

We would like to share with you the **Most Active Contributors Report** over the last month!

[image]

**This report includes the following awards:**

1. Monthly Leader Board.
2. Most Active Contributors Award.
3. Most Active Editors Award.
4. Most Active Voters Award.
5. Most Close Votes Review Award.
6. Most First Post Review Award.
7. Most Late Answer Review Award.
8. Most Low-Quality Posts Review Award.
9. Most Reopen Review Award.
10. Most Suggested Edit Review Award.
11. Highest Votes Questions Award.
12. Highest Votes Answers Award.
13. Most Viewed Questions Award.
14. 1st Top Contributors summary list.

---

[image]

[image]

You can find the full list at [Stack Exchange Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/105/month/sharepoint/2017-12-01)

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                   REPUTATION
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Mohamed El-Qassas MVP      1,025
2   Waqas Sarwar MVP           555
3   little_big_thoughts        351
4   Trevor Seward              325
5   LZ-WX                      316
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                    EDITS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Mohamed El-Qassas MVP     146
2   douvillema                76
3   Tally                     41
4   Danny '365CSI' Engelman   39
5   Waqas Sarwar MVP          31
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     VOTES
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Crazy Ivan                  196
2   Martin Tyler                71
3   Asad Refai                  67
4   P S                         53
5   Archiver SP                 46
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Mohamed El-Qassas MVP        17
2   Gaurravs                     16
3   moe                          11
4   Gautam Sheth                 4
5   Asad Refai                   4
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Mohamed El-Qassas MVP        59
2   Gaurravs                     52
3   P S                          26
4   moe                          24
5   Waqas Sarwar MVP             24
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Gaurravs                    18
2   Waqas Sarwar MVP            12
3   moe                         12
4   Mohamed El-Qassas MVP       9
5   Christoffer                 9
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Mohamed El-Qassas MVP       24
2   Gaurravs                    21
3   P S                         17
4   moe                         15
5   Waqas Sarwar MVP            14
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Gaurravs                     6
2   Mohamed El-Qassas MVP        3
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Mohamed El-Qassas MVP        67
2   Gaurravs                     37
3   Waqas Sarwar MVP             33
4   moe                          22
5   P S                          13
```

---

[image]

1. [Remove SharePoint from windows explorer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231976/remove-sharepoint-from-windows-explorer)

   - **Quest Owner:** FlorisdG.
   - **Votes:** 6.
2. [Environment not sending mail](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/232406/environment-not-sending-mail)

   - **Quest Owner:** Xablau Developer.
   - **Votes:** 6.

---

[image]

1. [CAML Query Logics](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/232970/caml-query-logics/232971#232971)

   - **Answer Owner:** Gaurravs.
   - **Votes:** 7.
2. [The Microsoft SharePoint Migration Tool](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/232142/the-microsoft-sharepoint-migration-tool/232143#232143)

   - **Answer Owner:** Mohamed El-Qassas MVP.
   - **Votes:** 6.
3. [How to create sections in list form Sharepoint2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/232008/how-to-create-sections-in-list-form-sharepoint2013/232014#232014)

   - **Answer Owner:** Vineet Desai.
   - **Votes:** 5.

---

[image]

1. [CAML Query Logics](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/232970/caml-query-logics/232971#232971)

   - **Views:** 291.
2. [What happens if SharePoint timer service stops?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231969/what-happens-if-sharepoint-timer-service-stops)

   - **Views:** 219.
3. [Migrating our SharePoint 2013 on-premises farm to an Office 365](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231863/migrating-our-sharepoint-2013-on-premises-farm-to-an-office-365)

   - **Views:** 159.

---

[image]

1. **Most Active Contributors Award.**

   - [Mohamed El-Qassas MVP](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/mohamed-el-qassas-mvp?tab=profile) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
2. **Most Active Editors Award.**

   - [Mohamed El-Qassas MVP](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/mohamed-el-qassas-mvp?tab=profile)  Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
3. **Most Active Voters Award.**

   - [Crazy Ivan](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/34941/crazy-ivan)  Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
4. **Most Close Votes Review Award.**

   - [Mohamed El-Qassas MVP](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/mohamed-el-qassas-mvp?tab=profile) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
5. **Most First Post Review Award.**

   - [Mohamed El-Qassas MVP](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/mohamed-el-qassas-mvp?tab=profile) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
6. **Most Late Answer Review Award.**

   - [Gaurravs](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/20302/gaurravs) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
7. **Most Low-Quality Posts Review Award.**

   - [Mohamed El-Qassas MVP](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/mohamed-el-qassas-mvp?tab=profile) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
8. **Most Reopen Review Award.**

   - [Gaurravs](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/20302/gaurravs) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
9. **Most Suggested Edit Review Award.**

   - [Mohamed El-Qassas MVP](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/mohamed-el-qassas-mvp?tab=profile) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
10. **Highest Votes Questions Award.**

    - [FlorisdG](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/72584/florisdg) Great Question, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
11. **Highest Votes Answers Award.**

    - [Gaurravs](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/20302/gaurravs) Great Answer, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
12. **Most Viewed Questions Award.**

    - [CAML Query Logics](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/232970/caml-query-logics/232971#232971)

---

Thank you so much all contributors for volunteering, We fully appreciate all the great contributions of all valuable SharePoint StackExchange members.

> **P.S.:** This report will be published Monthly / Quarterly / Yearly. Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback & precious suggestion!